# Symfony "This value should not be blank." while submitting form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to submit a user form. But the form does not contain all database fields because I want to set the password later (when submitting form).

But now I'm getting the error that the field 'password' should not be blank. Removing the form validation is not working and adding them as `HiddenType` is also not working.

I'm getting this error after the `$form->isValid()` check

EDIT:
FormBuilder

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('email', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Email adres',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'input-field'
                )
            ))
            ->add('first_name', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'label' => 'Voornaam',
                    'class' => 'input-field'
                )
            ))
            ->add('middle_name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Tussenvoegsel (optioneel)',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'input-field'
                )
            ))
            ->add('last_name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Achternaam',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'input-field'
                )
            ))
            ->add('date_of_birth', DateType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Geboortedatum',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'input-field'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Gebruiker Opslaan',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-submit-btn'
                )
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

Submitting the form:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted()){
            if($form->isValid()){
                dump($user);
                exit;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

Doing `$user->setPassword('123');` before validation is not working

Comment: By setting them as `HiddenType` you just hide the field, but the validation is still there. Can you post some code, form and validation?

Comment: If I add the password field as HiddenType and removing the validation, it is still not working

Comment: And the validation mapping file between entity and form?

Comment: Attach screenshot from [debug toolbar](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-improvements#easier-to-debug-form-errors).

Comment: @jkucharovic https://ibb.co/r6dXTbk

Comment: @GasKa Don't have validation in my entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your User Entity?

You may get the Error because an argument is not allowed to be blank.
Take a look at any `@Assert\NotBlank` or `nullable = false` Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your User class? May be implements UserInterface? So, there is this validation.